# Can I apply round corner and shadow to itunes 1024 icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, itunes

"the itunes icon submitted within iTunesConnect in the app management must not have rounded corners or gloss"

Can I add settings for "Prerendered" for it to have pre-set corner and gloss for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do any thing with the image. But I guess rounded will not be accepted because Itunes renders it itself. And if you put a shade. Itunes will put another shade in it so your image will not be shown as your need.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, it not recommended to put a shade on it, because Apple will apply their own one. In fact, your app may not be accepted. Also, there are another conditions for icons etc (read ITunes good practises).

Answer (score 0):

The area where the corners will be rendered (and they will be there, since the system adds them automatically! There is no way arround the corners.) is just never displayed anywhere. You can do what you want in that area, but it doesn't have any usage.

But I will not recommend you to add corners to your image, since the corner doesn't have the same radius in different situations/resolutions.